# Position text in the middle of each image

Tags: html, css, text, position

I am trying to do the following: I have two images next to each other, now in EACH image, I would like to display text, in the middle of that image.

So basically this is the text div that should be displayed in the middle:

```
<div class="overlay-text">
    <a href="about.html" title="about">
        <h3>text</h3>
    </a>
</div>
```

This is what I came up with so far: http://jsfiddle.net/R76df/2/

However, box the text divs (overlay-text) display on the same spot while the second `.overlay-text` should be displayed in the center of the second image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of extra HTML in there that you don't need.

Is this what you had in mind?

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/R76df/22/)

**Revised HTML**

```
<div class="about-big">
    <div class="about">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="about" />
        <a class="overlay-text" href="about.html" title="about">
            <h3>text</h3>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="about">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="about" />
        <a class="overlay-text" href="about.html" title="about">
            <h3>text fdsfddsfds</h3>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Revised CSS**

```
.about-big {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.about {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
}

.about img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 800px;
    display: block;
}

.overlay-text {
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    color:white;
}

.overlay-text {
    padding: 20px 28px;
    border: 4px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are applying the same style for both text. Try to shift second text to right.
Try to add this to your CSS and see if it fixes it.

```
.about-big2 .overlay-text {
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: It fixes it! But I don't really seem to understand what or how exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this makes sense. I made it so that .about-big1 and 2 were position:relative and set them to half width instead of the images.

http://jsfiddle.net/5CuxP/

```
.about-big img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 800px;
}

.about-big1, .about-big2{
    width: 49%;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
```